# What is the difference between 'tableView.contentSize' and 'tableView.frame.size'

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, frame, contentsize

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

It works, but I wonder what actually are those two values:
`tableView.contentSize`, `tableView.frame.size`

Comment: It's related to the `UIScrollView` part, about what's actually shown and what's the whole size in reality (counting the "hidden" content, not shown except if you scroll)

Comment: if you wanna go deep, take a look on [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/scroll-view.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `contentSize` is the size of the content of the `UIScrollView`, that means it will be the size of the content (hidden and visible) whereas the `frame.size` is the real size of your tableView.

For example, let's say I have a device's screen of 568 (height), and inside it, I have an `UITableView` (taking all the screen) with 100 cells and an height of 50 for each of them. My `tableView.frame.size.height` will be equal to 568, but the `tableView.contentSize.height` will be equal of the scroll's size of all the cells, so 5000.

Also, as suggested by @Ethaan, read [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/scroll-view.html) to go deeper.